# Vim Latex: Remove command around word/phrase easily

Tags: vim, latex

I am using vim-latex and I am searching for a solution to delete an attribute/a command around a phrase. E.g.

```
\textit{\textbf{Foo}}
```

shall become

```
\textit{Foo}
```

somehow. I found the "surroundings"-script which is powerful for single signs but unfortunately cannot achieve my goals.

Any ideas and hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) by Tim Pope this might do

```
nmap <silent> dsa ds}dF\
```

Comment: I like it more than my solution - less keystrokes!

Comment: Works like a charm for the inner attribute :-) 
But can I modify it to delete the attribute around the cursor's position? In my example above I want to delete `textit` and keep `textbf`…

Comment: Just position your cursor on `textit`'s `{` or just inside the `{`. It is probably easiest to think of the cursor as marking the part you want to keep.

Comment: Wow - this is more powerful than I thought. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like

```
F{dF\ds{

F{  "goes back to the last { before the cursor
dF\ "deletes the attribute
ds{ "deletes the {} (needing the surround-plugin
```

and put this to a new-vim-command like ds or something
but otherwise I don't know either.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), the default mapping is simply `dsc` (delete surrounding command).
You can issue it both when the cursor is on the command name or in the text.

Comment: @samcarter --- looking into chat now --- but you commented in the wrong site :-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508911/38080 --- thanks a lot by the way, that's the correct answer